# React Native - update useState in useRef

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state, use-ref

I am updating useState variable in a useRef:

```
const [swipeDirection, setSwipeDirection] = useState(false);
 const panResponder = useRef(
   PanResponder.create({
     onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
     onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
       if (gestureState.dy > 0 && gestureState.vy > 0) {
         if (
           (gestureState.vy >= 0.5 || gestureState.dy >= 100) &&
           !swipeDirection
         ) {
           // update state here
           setSwipeDirection(true);
           Animated.timing(position, {
             toValue: {x: 0, y: halfHeight - 40},
             ...TIMING_CONFIG,
             useNativeDriver: false,
           }).start(() => {
            
           });
         } else {
           // update state here
           setSwipeDirection(true);
       
           Animated.spring(position, {
             toValue: 0,
             useNativeDriver: false,
           }).start(() => {
         
           });
         }
       }
     },
   }),
 ).current;
```

SwipeDirection is not True what so ever
When I change swipeDirection to useRef - and update it(swipeDirection.current = true) it works.
What is the problem? There is a different queue to useRef and useState?

Comment: Are you trying to use a React ref to memoize a callback? Switching `swipeDirection` to a React ref and mutating it with `swipeDirection.current = true` works because it's a React ref. How are you trying to use the code above? How are you verifying that the `swipeDirection` as a state variable isn't working?

Comment: I swipe up the modal (initially modal is down) - swipeDirection is change to true (debugging it) but when I swipe down the modal swipeDirection is false